# SQLiteConstraintException: column id is not unique (code 19) exception when updating row

Tags: android, sqlite, android-database

I have a table in my database, when adding new record I am checking if the record exists using the id.If it does, I want to update the record and if it doesn't add a new record. But am getting the exception:

> 2006-2259/? E/SQLiteDatabase﹕ Error inserting id=080333 phone=080333 total_owed=15050.0 total_debts=0 name=Alison Jones
>       android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: column id is not unique (code 19)

This is the method that checks if a record exists:

```
 public boolean checkIfExists(String tableName, String value) {

    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getReadableDatabase();

    String Query = "Select * from " + tableName + " where " + DEBTOR_ID + " = " + value;
    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(Query, null);
    if(cursor.getCount() <= 0){
        cursor.close();
        return false;
    }
    cursor.close();
    return true;

}
```

and it is being used here:

```
            debtor.setDebtorName(params[0]);
            debtor.setPhoneNumber(params[1]);
            debtor.setTotalAmountOwed(Double.parseDouble(params[6]));
            debtor.setTotalDebts(0);

            if (databaseHandler.checkIfExists(DebtDatabaseHandler.DEBTOR_TABLE_NAME, params[1])) {
                Log.d("NewDebtFragment", "Record already exist");
                databaseHandler.updateRecord(2, debtor.getTotalAmountOwed() + 50000);
            } else {
                debtorId = databaseHandler.addDebtor(debtor);
            }
```

Since this is a conflict issue, obviously the check for existing record isn't working.I don't why this is because the code seem fine (?)

This is how am creating the table:

```
String CREATE_DEBTOR_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE  " + DEBTOR_TABLE_NAME + " ( " +
            DEBTOR_ID + " TEXT PRIMARY KEY, " +
            DEBTOR_NAME + " TEXT, " +
            PHONE_NUMBER + " TEXT, "+
            TOTAL_DEBTS + " INTEGER, " +
            TOTAL_OWED + " INTEGER) ";
```

and the `updateRecord` method:

```
 public void updateRecord(int newTotalDebt, double newTotalOwed) {

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(TOTAL_DEBTS, newTotalDebt);
    contentValues.put(TOTAL_OWED, newTotalOwed);

    db.update(DEBTOR_TABLE_NAME, contentValues, DEBTOR_ID, null);


}
```

Comment: Can you post create table query ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Replace your query with the below

```
 String Query = "Select * from " + tableName + " where " + DEBTOR_ID + " = '" + value+"'";
```

since selection `value` is string , it must be enclosed in single quote.

**Updated :** 
Instead of writing whole bunch code for checking whether record exits or not if exits then udpating that record, you can replace all these things with a simple single line.

```
database.insertWithOnConflict(table,null,values,SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_REPLACE);
```

It will internally handles the exception, `CONFLICT_REPLACE` it specifies that When a UNIQUE constraint violation occurs, the pre-existing rows that are causing the constraint violation are removed prior to inserting or updating the current row.

Comment: @ojonugwaochalifu updated the answer once have a look,

Comment: Thanks for the additional info.I'll try this out.